# Fire handler only once for multiple eventbindings

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling

I have more than one event binding

```
element.on("event1 event2 event3", function(event){};
```

I want it the function the execute only **once** when e.g. event1 and event2 are happening at the same time (e.g. keydown and keypress).

Answer (score 0):

Try e.preventDefault() http://jsfiddle.net/LENq8/

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="fld" />
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fld').on('keypress keydown', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(123);        
    })
})
```